# Manipulating Strings in Assembly (MASM)

Tags: string, assembly, masm

```
.data
    source  BYTE  "Defense mechanism",0
    target  BYTE  SIZEOF source DUP(0)

.code
    main PROC

        mov  esi, OFFSET target
        mov  edi, OFFSET target
        mov  ecx, SIZEOF source
    L1:
        mov  al,[esi]           ; get a character from source
        mov  [edi],al           ; store it in the target
        inc  esi                ; move to next character
        inc  edi
        loop L1
```

In the `.data` section, I see that `source` is defined as the string.
In the `.code` section, I see that the memory location of `target` is stored in the source index. Shouldn't I want the source index (`ESI`) to point to `source` instead of `target`? This program is supposed to copy a string into the target box that has been initialized to the size of the source string and to have each of the fields filled with zeroes. I have no experience with Assembly language. What am I getting wrong? (Note: this is how my professor has the program listed out, but he isn't offering any real material on this because this is a web based "security in computing" course.

Comment: Yes, you're right - esi should point at source, not target - it looks like your "professor" has at least one bug in that code.

Comment: @Paul R: that should be an answer, not a comment, imo

Comment: @Necrolis: you may be right - it didn't feel substantial enough to be an answer but maybe it does qualify - I'll move it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're right - `esi` should point at `source`, not `target` - it looks like your professor has at least one bug in that code. Change:

```
          mov  esi, OFFSET target
```

to:

```
          mov  esi, OFFSET source
```